# Why does the PayPal API not recognize my client id and secret

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

The Paypal API doesn't recognize my Client ID and Secret I got from https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

I wanted to include a server side checkout according to this tutorial https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/checkout/how-to/server-integration/

When I do the request to https://api-m.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment I always get a 401 Error with the message "Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.".
I checked multiple times if my credentials were correctly included into the request. I also tested the endpoint in my server environment and as well via Postman.
I also tried the route https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token to exchange my credentials with an access token and got the same problem.
I also tried to create multiple Sandbox and Live Accounts and always got the same error.

Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate issues here.

1. You first need to use /v1/oauth2/token to obtain an access token, and then use that access token to call any of the other actual APIs.
2. The credentials you obtain from [PayPal Developer](https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications) will be for either "Sandbox", or "Live". Make sure you choose the correct tab (sandbox, for development).  Sandbox credentials will only work for `api-m.sandbox.paypal.com` , and Live credentials will only work for `api-m.paypal.com` .  The two environments are completely separate.

If you still have issues, post the SANDBOX client ID and secret you are using, and the full request and response to the api-m.sandbox.paypal.com  endpoint.  There should be a PayPal-Debug-Id in any error response, in the headers if nowhere else.